# How to install pytorch on Power 8 or PPC64 machine?

Tags: pytorch, powerpc

I am trying to install **pytorch** using **conda** on **power 8 IBM machine**. Although, I read articles from [IBM blog](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/install-pytorch-on-power/), I couldn't install with success because I got stuck with compiling **magma**.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that **conda** is already installed.
Simply run the following command

```
conda install -c engility pytorch
conda install -c engility torchvision
```

Note:
1. Goto this [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/) page
2. Search for **pytorch**
3. Scroll down to see which one has **linux-ppc64le** as **platform**
4. Click into that specific package
5. You will get the command to install pytorch

Comment: This only works for Python 3.6 (not above) and will install a very old pytorch version (0.4.0).

Answer (score 3):

I finally installed PyTorch 1.5.0 on ppc64le server using conda environment.

1. Install **anaconda** (in my case I just installed miniconda3):
2. Add a new config **channel**:

```
conda config --prepend channels https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/server/ibm-ai/conda-early-access/linux-ppc64le/
```

3. Create a new conda **environment** and activate it:

```
conda create --name early_access python=3.6
conda activate early_access
```

4. Install **pytorch**:

```
conda install pytorch
```

That's it! Credits to this blog: https://gauravm.gitbook.io/about/blogs/installing-pytorch-and-transformers-on-ibm-powerpc-architecture

Comment: Is there any way to install the version with GPU supported? Every time I run this code I could only install the CPU version...

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use [powerai - MLDL framework from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/wmlce/1.7.0?topic=installing-mldl-frameworks), which includes PyTorch:

```
conda install powerai
```

It installs correct version of pytorch for PPC64.