# Pytorch AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'as_tensor'

Tags: python, pytorch, attributeerror, powerpc

```
$ python main.py --hetero
Created directory results/ACMRaw_2020-01-13_01-20-26
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 101, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "main.py", line 30, in main
    val_mask, test_mask = load_data(args['dataset'])
  File "/home/cnudi1/wook/dgl/examples/pytorch/han/utils.py", line 225, in load_data
    return load_acm_raw(remove_self_loop)
  File "/home/cnudi1/wook/dgl/examples/pytorch/han/utils.py", line 189, in load_acm_raw
    pa = dgl.bipartite(p_vs_a, 'paper', 'pa', 'author')
  File "/home/cnudi1/.conda/envs/lcr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dgl-0.4-py3.6-linux-ppc64le.egg/dgl/convert.py", line 260, in bipartite
    return create_from_scipy(data, utype, etype, vtype)
  File "/home/cnudi1/.conda/envs/lcr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dgl-0.4-py3.6-linux-ppc64le.egg/dgl/convert.py", line 823, in create_from_scipy
    indptr = utils.toindex(spmat.indptr)
  File "/home/cnudi1/.conda/envs/lcr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dgl-0.4-py3.6-linux-ppc64le.egg/dgl/utils.py", line 242, in toindex
    return data if isinstance(data, Index) else Index(data)
  File "/home/cnudi1/.conda/envs/lcr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dgl-0.4-py3.6-linux-ppc64le.egg/dgl/utils.py", line 15, in __init__
    self._initialize_data(data)
  File "/home/cnudi1/.conda/envs/lcr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dgl-0.4-py3.6-linux-ppc64le.egg/dgl/utils.py", line 22, in _initialize_data
    self._dispatch(data)
  File "/home/cnudi1/.conda/envs/lcr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dgl-0.4-py3.6-linux-ppc64le.egg/dgl/utils.py", line 75, in _dispatch
    self._user_tensor_data[F.cpu()] = F.zerocopy_from_numpy(self._pydata)
  File "/home/cnudi1/.conda/envs/lcr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dgl-0.4-py3.6-linux-ppc64le.egg/dgl/backend/pytorch/tensor.py", line 276, in zerocopy_from_numpy
    return th.as_tensor(np_array)
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'as_tensor'
```

I got an error when I try to run the code (https://github.com/dmlc/dgl/blob/master/examples/pytorch/han/main.py)

from the DGL 
(https://github.com/dmlc/dgl)

It requires CUDA and Pytorch so I managed to install it.

But I got an error and couldn't find the solution with Google/Stackoverflow search

My environment is

- Linux minsky 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.ppc64le
- CentOS
- Python 3.6.9
- Conda 4.5.11
- CUDA 10.1
- NVCC 10.1
- Pytorch 0.4.0
- Torchvision 0.2.1

Pytorch works fine in Python

```
>>> import torch
>>> print (torch.__version__)
0.4.0
>>> import torchvision
>>> print (torchvision.__version__)
0.2.1
```

Please could you help me out?

* DGL is installed from the source code

** Pytorch is installed with conda from channel:engility([How to install pytorch on Power 8 or PPC64 machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750622/how-to-install-pytorch-on-power-8-or-ppc64-machine))

```
conda install -c engility pytorch
```

because other ways(default conda, pip, install from the source code) never works for ppc64le

Comment: If you want to use pytorch on ppc64le, you should use IBM's conda channel. See: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS5SF7_1.6.2/navigation/welcome.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** Upgrade to PyTorch 0.4.**1**

---

Notice that DGL requires PyTorch 0.4.1 and you are using PyTorch 0.4.0. If you take a closer look, you'll see that `as_tensor` was [proposed in 30 Apr 2018](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/7109) and merged in 1 May 2018. You'll also see that PyTorch 0.4.0 was released before that on 24 Apr 2018, whereas [PyTorch 0.4.1](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/v0.4.1) was release after on 26 Jul 2018. In fact, if you take a look at the [changelog of the 0.4.1 version](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.4.1), you'll notice a new operator being announced: `torch.as_tensor` :)

Comment: Thanks!! It helps. For ppc64le, Pytorch only has 0.4.0 version so it is not possible to upgrade to 0.4.1 version. I guess I should find other solution

Comment: @crwarwa I had to use it in a cluster some months ago and I built it from source. If you can use conda, PyTorch 1.2 is available on IBM's conda channel: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/server/ibm-ai/conda/

Comment: It solved the problem!! I follow the constructions from the link and succeeded to install Pytorch 1.2.